# MDT 2010 Litetouch.vbs Fails to Launch

Tags: mdt-2010

I have the custom image captured.  Import the image and files.  Prepare the customsettings.ini and the boot.ini to minimize the questions the deployment team will need to answer.  Everything works like a charm on virtual machines but when I map to the scripts folder on the deployment share and double-click litetouch.vbs it creates the c:\minint folder, subfolders, and a couple of log files then nothing.  Here's what the log files look like:

`<![LOG[Property LogPath is now = C:\MININT\SMSOSD\OSDLOGS]LOG]!><time="15:54:28.000+000" date="03-08-2011" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Property CleanStart is now = ]LOG]!><time="15:54:28.000+000" date="03-08-2011" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 5.1.1642.01]LOG]!><time="15:54:28.000+000" date="03-08-2011" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Property Debug is now = FALSE]LOG]!><time="15:54:28.000+000" date="03-08-2011" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[GetAllFixedDrives(False)]LOG]!><time="15:54:28.000+000" date="03-08-2011" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">`

Anyone encounter this before or know what might be happening/not happening and can direct me in the right way?  I've only found a couple of other references to this anywhere and they had no solution/cause listed either.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

so you've created the reference machine and successfully captured it by correctly connecting to the deployment share\scripts folder and running litetouch.vbs.
You've now created a "deploy WIM" task sequence and are launching it by connecting to the share again in Windows? As far as I know you can't build a machine that way. You need to mount your boot WIM in Windows Deployment Services and launch it by booting from the network (usually by pressing F12 at the BIO screen). Does that make sense or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Thanks Kieran but in fact you can. : )  We were unable to figure out what the problem was in our lab but the process works like a champ in production.  So, create the reference and capture.  Then import the captured image with source files from an os disk.  Then running a litetouch iso or launching the litetouch.vbs will deploy the image.  You have to create a new task sequence in MDT. I still have no idea why it fails to launch in our lab.  What you describe works but requires WDS which we did not use.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I really didn't know you could do that. I'll be giving that a try in my own lab today :) Your log doesn't really give any clues as to what has failed for you - are there other log files in one of the subfolders or anything in the local eventlog seeing as you launch it in Windows?

Comment: No logs at all, which adds to the mystery.  I've seen a couple of posts in the Technet forums with people experiencing the same behavior but no responses and no suggestions.

Comment: Can you post the task sequence you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen LiteTouch.wsf fail to launch, or fail to get anywhere if it hasn't been run with elevated privileges. Running it as an admin worked for me in that scenario.